# Expressjs on Netlify Lambda function creates new session on every request

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, lambda, serverless

Good Evening,
When I run my Expressjs API locally without using lambda functions everything works, but once I introduce the lambda function it creates a new session on every request. The below is my `server.js` as well as `Dashboard.js` which shows how I am making calls.

The difference between local and local, but with lambda is that the lambda function that is the ExpressAPI is ran on `localhost:9000` and the React client is running on `localhost:3000`, but when I use ExpressAPI to also serve my React app everything is on `localhost:8080`

**NetlifyServer.js**

```js
'use-strict';

const express = require('express');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const axios = require('axios');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
require('dotenv').config()
process.env.SILENCE_EMPTY_LAMBDA_WARNING  = true


  // Middleware
  const saveLoggedInUserMiddleware = require('../Middleware/SaveLoggedInUserMiddleware');
  const hostValidationMiddleware = require('../Middleware/HostValidationMiddleware');
  const sessionValidationMiddleware = require('../Middleware/SessionValidationMiddleware');
  const updateUserDataMiddleware = require('../Middleware/UpdateUserDataMiddleware');

  //Routers
  const StoreInvoiceRouter = require('../Routes/Store-Update-Invoices');
  const UserInvoicesRouter = require('../Routes/GetUserInvoices');
  const UpdateUserProfileRouter = require('../Routes/UpdateUserProfile');


async function connectToDB() {
  
  // Database 
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.mongo_url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },  () => {
    
    console.log('[connectToDB]: Connected to DB'); 
  })
  
  }
  connectToDB();
  
  // Implemented a rate limiter which is a TEMPORARY FIX for the infinite loop by the useEffect
  const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: .1 * 60 * 1000, // 10 seconds limit
    max: 4 
  });

  // Creating the session in order to save user data to req.session
  app.use(
    expressSession({
          secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
          resave: false,
          saveUninitialized: false,
      })
  );
app.use('/.netlify/functions/NetlifyServer/fetchUserInvoices', limiter);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/.netlify/functions/NetlifyServer/', hostValidationMiddleware, sessionValidationMiddleware, StoreInvoiceRouter);
app.use('/.netlify/functions/NetlifyServer/', saveLoggedInUserMiddleware, UserInvoicesRouter);
app.use('/.netlify/functions/NetlifyServer/', updateUserDataMiddleware, UpdateUserProfileRouter);





  // Function makes call to endpoint that runs deletion login, this allows the client to only have to be refreshed once to
  // render changes on the frontend.
  async function updateDBCall() {
    
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_STORE_INVOICES}`;
    const axiosConfig = {
      method: 'get',
      url
      };
      await  axios(axiosConfig).catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
      console.log('[updateDBCall]: Executed call to STORE_INVOICES')
    };

 

  // Supporting functions
  updateDBCall(); 
  




  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on 8080`);
  });
  module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

**Dashboard.js**

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import axios from 'axios';
import LogRocket from 'logrocket';
// @material-ui/core
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

// core components
import GridItem from "components/Grid/GridItem.js";
import GridContainer from "components/Grid/GridContainer.js";
import Card from "components/Card/Card.js";
import CardHeader from "components/Card/CardHeader.js";
import CardIcon from "components/Card/CardIcon.js";
import CardFooter from "components/Card/CardFooter.js";
import Snackbar from "components/Snackbar/Snackbar.js";
import StorageIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Storage';
import MessageIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Message';
import styles from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/views/dashboardStyle.js";



export default function Dashboard() {




  // Abstracted Authentication variables
  const { user, isAuthenticated, isLoading,} = useAuth0();

  // Initilizing the state as an empty array because response is an object that is an array of objects
  var [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useState({});

  // Positioning State for notification
  const [tc, setTC] = useState(true);
  const [bl, setBL] = useState(true);


  // Styling
  const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);
  const classes = useStyles();  

  // Time Conversions
  const moment = require('moment'); 
  moment().format(); 



  const showNotification = (place) => {
    switch (place) {
      case "bl":
        if (bl) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            setBL(false);
          }, 2000);
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };  

  async function fetchUserInvoices() {

    // Making a call to external api
    await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_USER_INVOICES}`,)   
    .then(async (res) => {

      // Saving response to the invoiceResponse variable
      const invoiceResponse = await res.json();

      // Updating state to contain our object which is an array of objects
      setData(invoiceResponse);
      console.log('[fetchUserInvoices:', invoiceResponse);
      
    }).catch(err => err);

      
 }



  // send user data to a test endpoint in the backend (WORKS)
  async function sendLoggedInUser(info) {
    
    try {
      // Example is a POST call to API 
      const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SAVE_USER}`;
      const axiosConfig = {
        method: 'post',
        url,
        data: info
      };

    await  axios(axiosConfig).catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
    console.log('[sendLoggedInUser]: LoggedInUser sent to server');
      
    } catch (error) {
      
      console.log('[sendLoggedInUser]: An Error has Occured', error)
    }
  }

  async function updateDB() {
    
    

    try {
    
      // Below is a GET Call to API 
      const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_STORE_INVOICES}`;
      const axiosConfig = {
        method: 'get',
        url,
      };
    await  axios(axiosConfig).catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
      
    } catch (error) {
      
      console.log('[updateDB]: An Error has occured', error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    
    // setting the state to include the logged in user object to be sent to server.
    setLoggedInUser(user);
    
  }, [user])
  

  return (
    isAuthenticated && (
      <div>
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
          {data  ? invoiceData : <div>Invoices could not be retrieved at this time. PLease try to refresh or contact your Administrator.</div>}
          <Snackbar
                  place="tc"
                  color="info"
                  icon={MessageIcon}
                  message={`Welcome ${user.nickname}  
                  You have ${data.length} open Invoices`}
                  open={tc}
                  closeNotification={() => setTC(false)}
                  close
                />
          <Snackbar
                  place="bl"
                  color="success"
                  icon={StorageIcon}
                  message="Invoices Successfully fetched from Database."
                  open={bl}
                  closeNotification={() => setBL(false)}
                  close
                />
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
    )
   
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [express-session docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionoptions):

> **Warning** The default server-side session storage, `MemoryStore`, is purposely not designed for a production environment.

Since Lambda functions run in an ephemeral environment, you are going to lose that session storage in memory. That's why it creates a new session for every request.

You will need to use a [persistent store](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores) for express-session.

Comment: I did that using connect-mongo, but it kept creating new sessions. Is is possible you could post a code example using the proper configuration using connect-mongo? I am probably not using the proper configuraiton

Comment: I've never used connect-mongo or any of the other storage connectors. Instead, I decided to avoid using express-session all together.

Comment: What do you use instead?

Comment: I use a cookie on the client side.